# NDepend rule to warn if objects of a given type are compared using ==

Tags: reference, comparison, warnings, equality, ndepend

as the title says: I need a NDepend rule (CQLinq) for C#/.net code, that fires whenever instances of a given type are compared using == (reference comparison). In other words, I want to force the programmer to use .Equals.

Note that the type in question has no overloaded equality operator.

Is this possible? If so, how? :)

Thanks, cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code with see that for value type, `==` translate to the IL instruction: `ceq`. This kind of usage cannot be detected with NDepend.

```
     int i = 2;
     int j = 3;
     Debug.Assert(i == j);
     var s1 = "2";
     var s2 = "3";
     Debug.Assert(s1 == s2);
```

However for **reference types** we can see that a operator method named `op_Equality` is called.

```
 L_001d: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
```

Hence we just need a CQLinq query that first match all method named `op_Equality`, and then list all callers of these methods. This can look like:

```
let equalityOps = Methods.WithSimpleName("op_Equality")
from m in Application.Methods.UsingAny(equalityOps)
select new { m, 
             typesWhereEqualityOpCalled = m.MethodsCalled.Intersect(equalityOps).Select(m1 => m1.ParentType) }
```

This seems to work pretty well :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, matching the method "op_Equality" works, I found out the same - unfortunately, when I thought about it a bit more, I came to the conclusion I really needed the rule "warn if objects of a given type are compared using ==, but not if compared to null" - and this, I think, is impossible. So I worked around the issue by overloading the equality/inequality operators and handling my type as a value type. Anyway, thanks for the effort!

Comment: You are welcome Tim, "but not if compared to null" is indeed something that cannot be matched by NDepend

Comment: Patrick, Is there any way to return results like this involving classes that do not explicitly define an `operator ==` implementation?

Comment: No, here the query relies on the op_equality() method called, there is no such method to test with NDepend CQLinq when the operator is not explicitly defined